# `sp_core::hash::H256::random()` not found

Tags: hash

Trying to generate random 256 bytes hash-like data. But compiler tells

```
  error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `random` found for struct `H256` in the current scope
     --> /home/poh/pro/work/aratar/substrate-dev/trait/app-agents/src/lib.rs:262:23
      |
  262 |                 seed: hash::H256::random(),
      |                                   ^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `H256`
```

But, if I change `random` to `zero`, then everything compiles successfully. What did I miss?

Using substrate v0.9.25.

**Update**

How to reproduce:

- Clone 0.9.25 `git clone --recursive git@github.com:paritytech/substrate.git -b polkadot-v0.9.25`
- Apply this changes:

```
diff --git a/frame/assets/Cargo.toml b/frame/assets/Cargo.toml
index 9e98d4e15a..40421d3a8c 100644
--- a/frame/assets/Cargo.toml
+++ b/frame/assets/Cargo.toml
@@ -23,9 +23,9 @@ frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../su
 # `system` module provides us with all sorts of useful stuff and macros depend on it being around.
 frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../system" }
 frame-benchmarking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../benchmarking", optional = true }
+sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", default-features = false, path = "../../primitives/core" }
 
 [dev-dependencies]
-sp-core = { version = "6.0.0", path = "../../primitives/core" }
 sp-std = { version = "4.0.0", path = "../../primitives/std" }
 sp-io = { version = "6.0.0", path = "../../primitives/io" }
 pallet-balances = { version = "4.0.0-dev", path = "../balances" }
diff --git a/frame/assets/src/lib.rs b/frame/assets/src/lib.rs
index 3f9146c5d2..fad1825812 100644
--- a/frame/assets/src/lib.rs
+++ b/frame/assets/src/lib.rs
@@ -160,6 +160,7 @@ use frame_support::{
        },
 };
 use frame_system::Config as SystemConfig;
+use sp_core::hash;
 
 pub use pallet::*;
 pub use weights::WeightInfo;
@@ -504,6 +505,7 @@ pub mod pallet {
                        admin: <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source,
                        min_balance: T::Balance,
                ) -> DispatchResult {
+                       let x = hash::H256::random();
                        let owner = ensure_signed(origin)?;
                        let admin = T::Lookup::lookup(admin)?;
```

- `cargo check`

My setup is

```
$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/poh/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.62.1 (e092d0b6b 2022-07-16)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal test that shows this behavior?  I was able to get this to work using a very simple unit test

Comment: @ShannonWells, I updated the OP post with reproduction steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `sp_core` in your tests, then you can have it like this:

```rs
use sp_core::H256;
H256::random()
```

Make sure to include `rand` crate as a dev dependency.

Looks like the `H256::random()` function implementation is feature guarded via `rand` crate:

```rs
// Implementation for disabled rand crate support.
//
// # Note
//
// Feature guarded macro definitions instead of feature guarded impl blocks
// to work around the problems of introducing `rand` crate feature in
// a user crate.
#[cfg(not(feature = "rand"))]
#[macro_export]
#[doc(hidden)]
macro_rules! impl_rand_for_fixed_hash {
    ( $name:ident ) => {};
}

// Implementation for enabled rand crate support.
//
// # Note
//
// Feature guarded macro definitions instead of feature guarded impl blocks
// to work around the problems of introducing `rand` crate feature in
// a user crate.
#[cfg(feature = "rand")]
#[macro_export]
#[doc(hidden)]
macro_rules! impl_rand_for_fixed_hash {
    ( $name:ident ) => {
        impl $crate::rand::distributions::Distribution<$name> for $crate::rand::distributions::Standard {
            fn sample<R: $crate::rand::Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> $name {
                let mut ret = $name::zero();
                for byte in ret.as_bytes_mut().iter_mut() {
                    *byte = rng.gen();
                }
                ret
            }
        }

        /// Utilities using the `rand` crate.
        impl $name {
            <!--snip-->
            /// Create a new hash with cryptographically random content.
            pub fn random() -> Self {
                let mut hash = Self::zero();
                hash.randomize();
                hash
            }
        }
    };
}
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/parity-common/blob/77ddc33a2773bab5d7169f5f29199182713d463d/fixed-hash/src/hash.rs#L455-L528

Comment: No, I'm trying to use it in pallet. I updated the OP post with reproduction steps.

Comment: You will notice that `sp_core` has a dev dependency of the `rand` crate.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm trying to use random in runtime (which is wasm compiled). This article helps me to do proper (but weak) random in runtime https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/pallet-design/incorporate-randomness/